# " Migrated fom " message disappeared when scroll the page

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, migration, migrated-questions

Some days ago I saw a migrated question in Meta : [Why have SO users with more reputation so few questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203961/why-have-so-users-with-more-reputation-so-few-questions).

In the last session of the question there is a banner like **Migrated from Stack Overflow**

[image: With Mark]

But when I scrolled to bottom for reading the answer, the banner vanished:

[image: No Mark]

I refreshed the page it come again. Is that a bug ?

Comment: What browser? I cannot reproduce that on Chrome on OS X.

Comment: No repro (Firefox 25 on Win 7).

Comment: Did you click on something like "1 new answer" or "this post is edited"? Loading a post through AJAX is known to cause the message to disappear. I saw that "edited 17 sec ago". Most likely this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Firefox version 24 in windows 7 (Also I could not reproduce that bug now, currently there are two banners, migrated from and closed)

Comment: @Antony: Exactly, I did that

Comment: @MidhunMP There should be a dup somewhere about this. Let's see if I can find it.

Comment: @Antony: Thanks for the link, that question also don't have any answer

Comment: @MidhunMP: yet it perfectly explains the behaviour you saw.